# При каких случаях могут быть S lock на page в БД?

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server, многопоточность, распараллеливание

При каких случаях могут быть S lock на page в БД?
Искал эту информацию, но ничего не видно. Только нашел на [Table и Row](https://www.sqlshack.com/locking-sql-server/)
Какие вообще могут быть блокировки на page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> При каких случаях могут быть S lock на page в БД?

Разделяемые (*shared*) блокировки устанавливаются при чтении данных.

Тут, пожалуй, важно отметить, что чтение не подразумевает только лишь команду `SELECT`. Чтение может происходить (соответственно, *S*-блокировки могут устанавливаться) также и при выполнении команд `DELETE`, `UPDATE`, `INSERT` и `MERGE`.

Например, при выполнении такого запроса

```
UPDATE u
SET u.Disabled = 1
FROM Users u
    JOIN UserRoles ur ON ur.Id = u.RoleId
WHERE ur.RoleName = N'Agents';
```

изменяется таблица *Users*, но также осуществляется и чтение из таблицы *UserRoles*, поэтому к ней будут применяться блокировки *IS/S*-семейства.

Блокирование ресурсов в SqlServer динамическое. По-возможности блокировки применяются на самом низком (*fine grained*) уровне (*RID*, *KEY*) - это способствует улучшению параллелизма (*concurrency*) и ослаблению борьбы за ресурсы (*contention*). Однако содержание большого числа блокировок расходует память, поэтому (в зависимости от совокупности факторов) блокировки могут укрупняться (*lock escalation*), либо сразу происходить на менее гранулярных (*coarse grained*) уровнях. Блокировка уровня страницы (*PAGE*), как правило, не является следствием укрупнения с более низкого уровня (*RID*, *KEY*), т.к. по-умолчанию укрупнение происходит сразу до уровня таблицы (*OBJECT*).

Возьмём, например, такой запрос

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    u.RoleId
FROM Users u;
```

Если строк в таблице немного (скажем, десяток), то *S*-блокировки будут применяться низкоуровневые (*RID* либо *KEY*). Если же строк будет достаточно много, то при выполнении запроса можно будет наблюдать установку *S*-блокировок уровня страницы (*PAGE*).

---

> Какие вообще могут быть блокировки на page?

Для страниц могут применяться все три основных вида блокировок (*S*, *U*, *X*) и блокировок с намерением (*IS*, *IU*, *IX*), а также все три вида комбинированных блокировок (*SIU*, *SIX*, *UIX*).